# Pandas and sum and cum sum in same dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I use the below to create a sum and a cumsum.  But they are in two separate dataframes.  I want all in one

```
asp = np.array(np.array([0,0,1]))
asq = np.array(np.array([10,10,20]))
columns=['asp']
df = pd.DataFrame(asp, index=None, columns=columns)
df['asq'] = asq
df = df.groupby(by=['asp']).sum()
dfcum =df.cumsum()
```

How do I have both the sum and the cumsum in the same dataframe.  Totally not clear how to do this. Below is what I want

```
     asqsum cumsum
asp     
0     20      20
1     20      40
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Maybe you want this?

```
In [20]: df['asq_cum']=df['asq'].cumsum()

In [21]: df
Out[21]: 
     asq  asq_cum
asp              
0     20       20
1     20       40
```

Comment: You sir are the real MVP